# Getting a weird ClassNotDefFoundException on runtime with GWT

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt

I am deploying a web application based on GWT. When I compile, I don't get any errors, but in runtime, I get this one (not complete stack trace):

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParserException
at org.gvsig.remoteClient.sos.SOSClient.<init>(SOSClient.java:47)
at com.uji.project.server.ConnectServiceImpl.makeConnection(ConnectServiceImpl.java:18)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Caused by:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
```

I have read on this website that that is probably caused if one or more classes are not available on running time but, as seen, the error is caused by some problem with the XML parser, but I have the XML parser included in my lib folder. In detail, in the project's lib folder, it is possible to find 3 JAR files: **gwt-maps.jar**, **gwt-servlet.jar**, and **kxml2.jar***.

If I open "kxml2.jar" file I can see folder **org** that within has **xmlpull** folder, that within has **v1** folder and finally **XmlPullParserException.class**.

So...why on runtime do I not have this class available if it is included on the lib folder?

Comment: Is that lib folder being included in the CLASSPATH at runtime?

Comment: If I right-click on the project, preferences, Java Build Path and Libraries tab, I see that all these 3 .jar files are on that list. But if I do Window, preferences, java build path and class variables I see that "lib folder" is NOT on the list...Which one do you mean? Thanks!

Comment: have you tried adding xmlpull-.jar instead of kxml2.jar ? See these jars in: http://www.findjar.com/class/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParserException.html

Comment: I downloaded "xmlpull-1.1.3.1.jar", copied it on the "lib" folder, added it to the "build path", rebooted Eclipse and launched again the application...but I got the same error.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I left other three jar files on the "lib" folder, so now I have those four.

Comment: Have you recompiled the aplication when you changed the jars?

Comment: What I do is right-click on the project, Run As, Web application. I thought this action recompiles again the files and deploys the application on Jetty. If this action does not recompile the code, please, could you tell me what to do for just compiling? [EDIT] Oh I just saw Run As - "Compile GWT Application". I will try this. :)

Comment: @Irene Run as/Web Application doesn't recompile the GWT code. Be careful with this every time you change the code you should recompile it by pressing the GWT icon. It has happened to me several times :)

Comment: I changed "kxml.jar" by "xmlpull.jar", recompiled and got the same error again. Then I put both files together, recompiled again and same problem on runtime.

Comment: Hehe, I didnt know because when I was designing the interface, as long as I was doing little changes they directly appear on the interface, so I thought that would compile the code again dynamically. Anyway, the recompilation & deploying is not working for me, still I am getting the same error. Any other idea? Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally a colleague told me the solution to this runtime error! :D

When a GWT application is deployed, many files are copied under a small file structure (pending from ) that contains all classes, libraries and other files that are needed on runtime.

For some reason, if you don't tell on purpose Eclipse to copy (on compile/deploy time) a specific library into that PATH, the application will not find on runtime that library and will raise an error.

Solution (for me) was as simple as copying by hand that library into that folder: In my case was copying **"kxml2.jar"** under **"C:\gwt-2.1.0\SOSProject\war\WEB-INF\lib"**. I restarted the application and just worked. :D

I hope this patch/solution will help others to solve this annoying problem under GWT!

Answer (score 1):

In appengine classes can only access to the classesof the JRE which are in this  [whitelist](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/jrewhitelist.html). If this jar is using another class of the JRE it won't be included in runtime.

[Here](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/WillItPlayInJava) you can read that "XML processing APIs including DOM, SAX, and XSLT" are compatible with appengine. Maybe xmlpullparser is not compatible, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
Window->Preferences->Java Build Path->Add Jars
Navigate to your project/lib, select kxml2.jar Hit OK.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, what I did was to start again from the beginning: In the same workspace I had different projects and maybe there were, let's say, interferences between them.

So, I unzipped again the GWT SDK, start a new project, copied the original source code on the new project, deployed it and on runtime, now I am not getting that weird ClassNotDefFound error. Now I am getting another one, but that is another issue! Thanks to all.